# Can't decode &rsquo; with php functions in ISO-8859-1 format

Tags: php, encode, iso-8859-1, apostrophe

I have a problem trying decoding `&rsquo;` to `'`.

In my php file I create a file.txt using this function:

```
fopen($fileName, "w");
```

Then, I get some strings from different variables and stock them into my var $texte:

```
$texte = "my content";
```

After this, I want to convert my $texte variable into an iso-8859-1 file, so:

```
$texte = mb_convert_encoding($texte, "ISO-8859-1");
```

That work but my special characters into this file are not decoded. So my apostrophes are transformed into -> `&rsquo;`

So after that, I've tried this:

```
 $texte = mb_convert_encoding($texte, "ISO-8859-1");
 $texte = html_entity_decode($texte, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Nothing changed, the apostrophe stayed the same -> `&rsquo;`

Trying with the same function but removing parameters changed once again the result:

```
$texte = html_entity_decode($texte);
```

Output: `‚Äô` instead of `'`.

Can anyone give me some help please?

Thank you in advance

Best regards 
Dan

Comment: You can use 'UTF-8' instead of "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: No, I have to use ISO-8859-1 because the file text generated has to be in this encoding mode.

Comment: If I juste convert my text using only this `$texte = html_entity_decode($texte);` without converting in ISO-8859-1, the output of my text apostrophe is: ` ’ ` and not  ` ' ` like I want.

Comment: I maybe found a solution, I used 
`$texte = html_entity_decode($texte);
$texte = str_replace("’","'", $texte);
$texte = mb_convert_encoding($texte, "ISO-8859-1");`.

Using str_replace function make that working.